# I need to calculate the grand total of each row in my Cost table in rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my costs table I have created a variable to calculate the rate multiplied by the hours and I can obtain my figure successfully. However, I need to calculate the total of each row at the end of my table. One of my fields are "total of all rows". What is the best course of action for this?
Any suggestions?
In my costs/index.html.erb file this is the code I currently have

```
<tbody>
<% @costs.each do |cost| %>
  <tr>

    <td><%= cost.mini_description %></td>
    <td><%= cost.description %></td>
    <td><%= cost.quantity %></td>
    <td><%= cost.rate %></td>
    <td><%= cost.total%><%=cost.cost_var%></td>
    <td><%= cost.total_of_all_rows %></td>
    <!--<td><%#= cost.job %></td>-->

    <td><%= link_to 'Show', cost %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cost_path(cost) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', cost, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
 </tbody>
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Total of all rows</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

I have fixed my code yet I am still not getting the desired result  my total_of_all_rows is not adding up the sum of rate and quantity. My amended code is:

```
  <tbody>
<% @costs.each do |cost| %>
  <tr>

    <td><%= cost.mini_description %></td>
    <td><%= cost.description %></td>
    <td><%= cost.quantity %></td>
    <td><%= cost.rate %></td>
    <td><%= cost.total%><%=cost.cost_var%></td>

    <!--<td><%#= cost.job %></td>-->

    <td><%= link_to 'Show', cost %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cost_path(cost) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', cost, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Total of all rows</th>
</tr>
</thead>
  <tr>
    <td><%= cost.total_of_all_rows %><%=Cost.sum(:total) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
```

My migration for this table is

```
 class CreateCosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
 create_table :costs do |t|
  t.string :mini_description
  t.string :description
  t.string :quantity
  t.string :rate
  t.string  :total
  t.string  :total_of_all_rows
  t.references :job, index: true

  t.timestamps
 end
end
```

end

Comment: Can you show any code that you currently have and/or what you have tried?

Comment: @AaronSiciliano I have added the current code that I have. Thank you

Comment: Why don't you declare a variable outside of the scope of the for each loop and initialize it with a value of 0. Then increment it by the value of cost.total inside of the foreach loop and by the end of the loop you will have the total cost. Or am i misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @AaronSiciliano I will try and let you know  thank you.

Comment: ¿Where is @costs coming from?

Comment: what is: cost.total_of_all_rows ¿a method or an attribute?

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos it isa table head. My information is not saving in the database but saving on the show screen, this is why I believing the.sum method is not working.

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos I am very lost right now nothing is saving to my database :(

Comment: This method is not suposed to save anything from the database. It just sums all the rows stored. If you want to store anything in the database you are going to do this in a model or controller, not in the view.

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos so if i am supposed to do it in the model do i have to create a method?

Comment: Can you add more info on what you are trying to do? I thought you want to sum all rows in a model column and display the result.

Comment: I want to sum the total of all the rows under the "total" section. So if my total for entry is 80 and then 60 I want the total of all rows to add it together and then display the result

Comment: @JorgedelosSantosI think i need to change the data type in my database because currently they are both total and total_of_all_rows are string. I believe I have to change them to floats.

Comment: You are storing the total_of_all_rows in the databse, In which table? Why are you storing a variable value? You will have to update ALL rows if you are storing it on each row.

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos My problem is that the .sum method is not calculating the grand total of each and every one of my rows which has the name "total"

Comment: Cost has a column named total. And you want to sum all the rows from this column. That is what .sum do. And the returns the same type as the column (integer, float). No row should be skipped while using this method. ¿Is that what you need?

Comment: @Jorgedelossantos No Still working on it

Comment: Paste migration for this table and model structure.

Comment: @jorgedelossantos I added the migration. Please have a look & let me know what you suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)Don't store the total_of_all_rows in the databse as long as it is variable and you will have to update it with each new entry.
2)Delete column from migration.

3)In your view:

```
<tbody>
  <% @costs.each do |cost| %>
  <tr>

    <td><%= cost.mini_description %></td>
    <td><%= cost.description %></td>
    <td><%= cost.quantity %></td>
    <td><%= cost.rate %></td>
    <td><%= cost.total%><%=cost.cost_var%></td>

    <!--<td><%#= cost.job %></td>-->

    <td><%= link_to 'Show', cost %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cost_path(cost) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', cost, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Total of all rows</th>
</tr>
</thead>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @costs.sum(:total) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<tbody>
```

If you still want to store the value:

```
class Cost < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_save :update_totals

  def update_totals
    Item.all.each {|x| x.total_of_all_rows = Item.sum(:total)
  end
end
```

Comment: I used this and I am getting errors :  <td><%= cost.total_of_all_rows %><% cost.sum(cost_var) %></td>"

Comment: That's because you are doing a sum of all columns in a single object. You have to do Cost.sum(:column_name) If you want to sum all the columns :column_name for the Cost table. But if you you want to do it just for the array you have, then you have to do:
@costs.sum(:cost_var)

Comment: I apologize I am still new to rails so what I have done now is the following : "<td><%= cost.total_of_all_rows %><%=cost.sum(total) %></td>" and I am still not achieving anything. Is there a problem with my syntax?

Comment: AS I todl you, you are not Accesing Cost table, you are just accessing cost elemento from your .each. You need to do (C)ost with capital C

Comment: Now I am getting the error "NoMethodError in Costs#index" :undefined method `sum' for #<Cost:0x007feb88cc4f40>" where do I go from here? to the index?

Comment: Thank you, so now I am not getting an error yet it is still now calculating the rows. I have value 0.00

Comment: I'm gonna need more data in the code. I don't know what are you trying :P

Comment: I have reposted my amended code. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Added a (I think) solution and some hints.

Comment: ok great. Thank you. I will try it out & I hope it will work. Do i have to synchronize the database afterwards or include anything in my command line?

Comment: If this is in production you will have to create a new migration with the down colum command. That is for another question. This just solves the view problem. Don't forget to give me feedback!

Comment: No unfortunately it has not worked. I am still unable to get the total of al the rows.

Comment: If you do in the console: Cost.all.sum(:cost) what does the output says? (Assuming you have some costs in the db)

Comment: I get this error when I run it in the console : ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: cost: SELECT SUM(cost) AS sum_id FROM "costs"

Comment: Sorry. Cost.all.sum(:total) is the right column I guess.

Comment: do you mean i have to put Cost.all.sum(:total) in the console? I am sorry but I am a little bit confused...

Comment: rails console > puts Cost.all.sum(:total)

Comment: i did and it returned 0.00

Comment: Where is this total row coming from? Is the result of quantity*rate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56375/discussion-between-jorge-de-los-santos-and-coding-kat).